# Compiler error after upgrade to Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 and g++ 7.3.0

Tags: 18.04, compiling, g++

As said in the title, I just upgraded to Ubuntu Bionic, 18.04, which comes with g++ 7.3.0. Since then I get these compiler error messages:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6349,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /home/rene/projects/Celma/develop/src/celma/appl/arg_string_2_array.hpp:22,
                 from /home/rene/projects/Celma/develop/src/library/appl/arg_string_2_array.cpp:19:
/usr/include/c++/7/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
```

I already replaced all

```
   #include <cstdlib>
```

by

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
```

but as the error message shows, these includes also happen inside the C++ library include files, so this does/did not help ...

And I can't believe that I am the only one with this problem? But I did not find another entry that matches my problem.

Update:
What I did: I manually changed all `#include_next <...>` in the system header files to "normal" `#include <...>`
Now it compiles. But this can't be the solution, can it?

Update 2:
As requested, the out of "cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null"

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=cpp
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-o' '/dev/null' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu /dev/null -o /dev/null -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-o' '/dev/null' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Comment: Please post the output of cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null so we can see what your standard include search path is.

Comment: Looks pretty standard. Do you have the libstdc++-7-dev package installed?

Comment: libstdc: Yes, I do. Somehow I have the feeling that it might be related to Boost, maybe Boost.Test, but could not verify this yet.

Comment: I installed the libboot-test-dev with no adverse effects on compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem. Switching from system includes (-isystem) to regular includes (-I) "fixed" the build - at the cost of seeing compiler warnings about third party libraries.

Comment: I will try that if the problem re-occurs after the next update/upgrade. I am using -isystem too, so this could be the same problem.

Comment: This really solves the problem. In my case it came from using the Boost library, where I had a `-isystem ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}` in my `CMakeLists.txt` file. Since the Boost library header files are in `/usr/include/boost`, this resulted in `-isystem /usr/include` which lead to the error described above.